# C++ new with empty curly braces init triggers cppcheck uninitvar error

Tags: c++, cppcheck

Please help me understand why cppcheck is blaming that particular line of code `test.cpp:6:11: error: Uninitialized variable: inst1 [uninitvar]` referring to `Test* inst1 = new Test{};` line

cppcheck --version =
Cppcheck 1.90

```
#include <tuple>
class Test{};

auto foo()
{
    Test* inst1 = new Test{};
    Test* inst2 = new Test;
    Test* inst3 = new Test();

    return std::make_tuple(inst1, inst2, inst3);
}

int main
{

}
```

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization `()` and `{}` should be same in this case.

I edited description because of people's claim that provided snippet is unreal, sorry about that. It was a typo in a variable name.

Comment: Is that your _real code_?  I'd imagine cppcheck also complaining about `int main{}`

Comment: @DrewDormann Bizarrely enough, it doesn't. cleaning it up to `int main()` still exhibits the same behavior though.

Comment: Assuming this is your real code, you found a bug in cppcheck.  They'd probably appreciate a bug report.

Comment: no it aint, it's a simplifyied version of legacy code 
I just wanted to have simple example of different kind of initialization in one piece
and cppcheck doesn't blame main even thou no return statement provided

Comment: There is no `instance` in the code. The code is not real.

Comment: Interestingly as well, adding a default constructor to `Test` does satisfy cppcheck.

Comment: real code looks like 
Super* getInstance()
{
  Super* s = new Derrived {};
  return s;
}

Comment: @S.M. fixed, thanks

Comment: *cppcheck doesn't blame main even thou no return statement provided*. It should not. The return statement in main is optional.

Comment: @Frank not it aint. Adding user-defined default c-tor aint change a thing for me.

Comment: @SoupEndless you should specify the version of cppcheck you're using

Comment: @S.M. It was a typo. I've edited the question. Basically:
Test* instance = new Test{}; triggers cppcheck error [uninitvar]

Comment: @ben10 Cppcheck 1.90, installed today

Comment: @SoupEndless just tested on 2.4, it's still there... it acts weirdly tho, complains about that, but not about: `Test inst6;`, not `Test inst5{};`, ...

Comment: @S.M. yep `cppcheck --version     Cppcheck 2.4.1`

Comment: @RichardCritten I did provide reproducible example. And you've start asking me about `real code`. Can you decide what do you want?

Answer (score 3):

This looks indeed like a false positive. I filed a ticket for this - see https://trac.cppcheck.net/ticket/10698.

Comment: This has been fixed in the upcoming Cppcheck 2.8.